# Merging two sorted list of different types (String and Integer) in Java using Lambda

Tags: java, list, lambda, merge, java-8

Merging the lists [“A”, “XYZ”, “AXTU”] and [2, 4, 6]

where the first list is sorted by word length. If a string length in the first list is the same as a number in the second list, the string comes first should produce like this:

> [“A”, 2, “XYZ”, “AXTU”, 4, 6].

I tried like this:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream().map(val -> Integer.toString(val)));
    System.out.println(stream.sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

and the output is like this:

> [2, 4, 6, A, AXTU, XYZ]

Any idea to solve this problem? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: it's not gonna work. describe your intention. what are you trying to solve with such idea?

Comment: You need a custom sort function that provides the rules you've laid out for the order.  For example using [this `sorted` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) that takes a `Comparator` instance.

Comment: Mixing different types in one collection like this is going to be a hideous mess no matter what.  You're almost certainly better off finding a better solution to your real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly convoluted because of the mixed types, but here is one way it could be done entirely with lambdas:

```
Stream<Object> stream = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream());
System.out.println(stream.sorted((Object o1, Object o2) ->
    (o1 instanceof String ? 2*((String)o1).length() : 1+2*(Integer)o1)
    - (o2 instanceof String ? 2*((String)o2).length() : 1+2*(Integer)o2)
  ).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The basic idea is to define a lambda that compares the length (if it's a string) to the value (if it's an integer) using the standard compareTo logic `a - b`.  However, to handle the case of a tie I've multiplied all the values by `2`, and then added an extra `1` to the `Integer` values.  This causes `Integer` to be sorted last in the case of a tie.

Demo: http://ideone.com/39ppGD

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat simpler solution is to use [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```
List<Object> result = Stream
    .concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(
        obj -> obj instanceof String ? 2 * ((String) obj).length() : 1 + 2 * (Integer) obj))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

The fact that your `List`(s) mix types (and given your conditional test is `String` length), I think you'll find it easiest to use a modifyable `Collection` and you'll need to iterate the first `List` continually. The fact that it's sorted doesn't help, since your merge criteria is *length* (for example, `Z` is one letter but the last [lexically](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lexical));

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "XYZ", "AXTU"));
List<Integer> bl = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6);
List<String> merged = new ArrayList<>();
for (int len : bl) {
    Iterator<String> iter = al.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String str = iter.next();
        if (str.length() <= len) {
            merged.add(str);
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    merged.add(String.valueOf(len));
}
System.out.println(merged);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
[A, 2, XYZ, AXTU, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, just using basic coding techniques, you can do it like this

```
public class zipMergeAndOrderSort {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array1 = new String[]{"A", "XYZ", "AXTU"};
    int[] array2 = new int[]{2, 4, 6};

    String[] newArray = new String[array1.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){ //merges arrays over
        newArray[i * 2] = " " + array1[i];

        String spaces = ""; //creates the right number of spaces
        for (int j = 0; j < array2[i]; j++){
            spaces += " ";
        }

        newArray[(i*2)+1] = spaces + array2[i];; //adds spaces based on number
    }

    boolean running = true; //sorts
    while (running){
        running = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < newArray.length - 1; k++){
            if (newArray[k].length() > newArray[k+1].length()){
                running = true;
                String temp = newArray[k];
                newArray[k] = newArray[k+1];
                newArray[k+1] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    //removes spaces
    for (int l = 0; l < newArray.length; l++){
        newArray[l] = newArray[l].trim();
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
        System.out.print("[" + newArray[i] + "] ");
    }
 }

}
```

If you want the letters to always come before the numbers (of the same length/number), you can just add in 1 more section that uses the same bubble-sort technique to push the numbers (or letters) to the right.